# "Trial" Ubuntu freezes as soon as it loads up

Tags: boot, 18.04

I'm currently trying to switch my OS. I'm trying to use Ubuntu 18.04 on a bootable flash-drive to merge my SSD's partitions first but every time the desktop loads up it just freezes after a second or so. The only thing that still works is the mouse.
I currently have Elementary OS installed and it works without issue. 
Anyone has any idea what the issue might be?
Need more information about the computer?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: EDIT: I'm going to try and run Ubuntu in safe mode from the usb (not even sure if that's possible).
If it doens't work I'll try an older version.
I think the problem is Ubuntu using only the processor to run everything.

Comment: EDIT: Couldn't find safe mode but an older version worked perfectly. I used Ubuntu 16.10 and finally modified my partitions with GParted. I still don't know why newer versions didn't work but at least my issue is gone.
Thank you for the attention. :)